# Discards inside C# Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, c#-7.0

I wonder if that's good pattern to use Discards in Linq queries according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards, example:

```
public bool HasRedProduct => Products.Any(_=>_.IsRed == true);
```

What's pros / cons instead using

```
public bool HasRedProduct => Products.Any(x=>x.IsRed == true);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That isn't a discard - it's a lambda expression parameter called `_`. It falls into the note later in the article:

> Note that `_` is also a valid identifier. When used outside of a supported context, `_` is treated not as a discard but as a valid variable.

You can tell it's not a discard because its value *isn't discarded* - you're using it in the rest of the lambda expression. I would *strongly* discourage the use of `_` as a lambda expression parameter name when you *are* using the value. It's fine to use `_` as a parameter name when you *want* to discard it though, even if it's not technically a discard from a language perspective. The name `_` was chosen for discards precisely because that's how it was already being used in practice.

Comment: Can we say that discards aren't available in linq/lambdas? *Supported context* is broad. But then there is also statement *"A standalone `_` when no `_` is in scope"*. How is local variable `_` a discard then if you can use it?

Comment: @Sinatr: That means assigning directly to `_` rather than *declaring* it as a local variable. For example, `_ = 5;` without `_` otherwise in scope is a discard. `int _= 5;` is a regular local variable declaration. But discards *can* be used in LINQ - for example, you could use `.Where(text => int.TryParse(text, out _))` to filter out strings that can't be parsed as integers.

Answer (score 1):

Those underscores are just lambda parameters named `_` as they did in C# 6. They are not discards.

Discards where introduced in C# 7 in some new contexts (for example, out variable declarations) and some existing contexts (for example, assignment `_ = expression;`). In the latter case, the C# 6 interpretation of the underscore wins, if one exists, to respect backwards compatibility.

> Discards are variables which you can assign to, but cannot read from.
>   They don't have names. Instead, they are represented by an '_'
>   (underscore). In C#7.0, they can appear in the following contexts:
>
> - out variable declarations, such as `bool found = TryGetValue(out var _)` or `bool found = TryGetValue(out _)`
> - deconstruction assignments, such as `(x, _) = deconstructable;`
> - deconstruction declarations, such as `(var x, var _) = deconstructable;`
> - is patterns, such as `x is int _`
> - switch/case patterns, such as `case int _:`
>
> The principal representation of discards is an `_` (underscore)
>   designation in a declaration expression. For example, `int _` in an
>   out variable declaration or `var (_, _, x)` in a deconstruction
>   declaration.
>
> The second representation of discards is using the expression `_` as a
>   short-hand for `var _`, when no variable named `_` is in scope. It is
>   allowed in out vars, deconstruction assignments and declarations, and
>   plain assignments (`_ = IgnoredReturn();`). It is, however, not
>   allowed in C#7.0 patterns. When a variable named `_` does exist in
>   scope, then the expression `_` is simply a reference to that variable,
>   as it did in earlier versions of C#.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/discards.md

Answer (score -4):

> Discards, which are temporary, dummy variables that are intentionally unused in application code. Discards are equivalent to unassigned variables; they do not have a value. Because there is only a single discard variable, and that variable may not even be allocated storage, discards can reduce memory allocations. Because they make the intent of your code clear, they enhance its readability and maintainability.

That means that these variables are not going to be used in your code and as written, they do not have value. So your query should throw null reference exceptions (because that `_` is unassigned

Comment: If it were unassigned, the compiler would complain when it was used. However, in this case it's not a discard anyway. The code presented was valid in earlier versions of C#, and remains valid with the same meaning.